# DFS Namespace Server Configuration

Tags: windows-server-2016, dfs

in my environment I have 2 DCs (DC01 and DC02). So, I added DFS roles in both of them. I created a domain based namespaces. The DFS replication role was installed on separate servers which are containing the files to be shared (DFS1 and DFS2). Till that moment everything worked very well. When I used to open **\\mydomain.local\** I was able to see all links which were created.

One on the DCs got crashed, so I had to re-install the OS and promote the new installation to AD DC after removing the old DC02 from Domain Controllers list (Administrative Tools -> Active Directory Users and Computer, Administrative Tools -> Active Directory Sits and Services). I added DFS Management role to the new DC02. On DC01, I had removed the DC02 from **Namespace Servers** from each created namespace.

When I am trying to add the new DC02 into the Namespace Server I am getting the path as: **\DC02\share_name** yet the current one is **\DC01.mydomain.local\share_name**

Also, when I am viewing **\\mydomain.local\** I am able only to see **SYSVOL** and **NETLOGON** unless I am issuing **ipconfig /flushdns** from CMD, then I will be able to see the rest of the links.

Please note:

1- DC01 is running on Windows Server 2016

2- Old DC02 was running on Windows Server 2016

3- New DC02 is running on Windows Server 2012 (I have changed the forest/domain functional level to Windows Server 2012 on DC01).